# TypeError: VariableMetaclass._variable_v1_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experimental_enable_variable_lifting'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, typeerror, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am getting this `TypeError` while creating a `keras` model from `TensorFlow` inside the `__init__` method of a custom class, any ideas?

My code:

```
self.model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1, input_dim=self.degree),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])
self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
self.model.summary()
```

Error:

```
self.model = keras.Sequential([
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py", line 205, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 285, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: VariableMetaclass._variable_v1_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experimental_enable_variable_lifting'
```

Tensorflow version information:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.12.0rc1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-intel
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `TensorFlow` upgrade to version `2.12.0` from `2.12.0-rc1` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue. Have you tried installing keras 2.12.0rc1?
I tried it here (pip install keras==2.12.0rc1 --user) and it seems to be working now.

Comment: I have tensorflow==2.12.0rc1, I get this error on my Win10 laptop but it works fine on MacBook.. not sure what triggers the failure in my laptop... both have intel i5 CPUs.

Comment: I tried this and it works.