# TypeError: VariableMetaclass._variable_v1_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experimental_enable_variable_lifting' - also in TF 2.12.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, sequential

This question was asked here and answer was provided for tensorflow version : `2.12.0rc1`
[TypeError: VariableMetaclass._variable_v1_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experimental_enable_variable_lifting'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728844/typeerror-variablemetaclass-variable-v1-call-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argum)

but it is still valid for tensorflow 2.12.

If I declare:

```
encoder = [
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32, 24, 1,)),
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation="gelu"
    )
]

tf.keras.Sequential(encoder).layers
```

Fails with:
`TypeError: VariableMetaclass._variable_v1_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experimental_enable_variable_lifting'`

If I try:

```
encoder = [
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32, 24, )),
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation="gelu"
    )
]
```

It will raise error due to dimensions in `InputLayer`:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_61" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 32, 24)
```

It seems the error is with `InputLayer`.

Python and TF Versions:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
#3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]
#2.12.0
```

I just reinstalled the TF clean of cache on a virtual environment.
Still fails.

Any idea how to fix this error?

The trace did not help in locating the issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[98], line 1
----> 1 tf.keras.Sequential(encoder).layers

File /data0/home/h21/luas6629/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py:205, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    203 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    204 try:
--> 205   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    206 finally:
    207   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File /data0/home/h21/luas6629/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /data0/home/h21/luas6629/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:285, in VariableMetaclass.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    282 @traceback_utils.filter_traceback
    283 def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    284   if cls is VariableV1:
--> 285     return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    286   elif cls is Variable:
    287     return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: VariableMetaclass._variable_v1_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experimental_enable_variable_lifting'
```